# httr POST request error: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination

Tags: r, curl, post, httr

I am currently trying to upload a CSV file to a proprietary service via `httr::POST()`. Unfortunately the Admins are not experienced in R and can give only little support.

This is an example on how it should look like in the command line:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F file=@"member-1-test.csv.gz"  'https://some/api/endpoint'
```

So, in the following code I just try to stick with the example (and additionally provide a token).

```r
> library(tidyverse)
> library(httr)

# Provide some test data with characters specifically quoted
> test_file <- tibble::tribble(
   ~keytype, ~key, ~action, ~segment,
   6,"\"https://www.google.com\"", 0, 37372818,
   6,"\"https://www.sport1.de\"" , 0, 37372818
 )

> data.table::fwrite(test_file, "test.csv", quote = FALSE)


> file <- upload_file(path = "C:/R/projects/DefaultWorkingDirectory/test.csv")

> res <- POST(
   
   url = "https://some/api/endpoint",
   
   body = list(file = file),
   
   add_headers(.headers = c('Content-Type' = "multipart/form-data", "Authorization" = token))
 )
```

This gives me the follwing error:

```r
> res
Response [https://some/api/endpoint]
  Date: 2020-11-18 09:35
  Status: 503
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Size: 95 B

> content(res, encoding = "UTF8")
"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination"
```

Any help or guidance on how to move forward with this issue is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Directly after posting the question it was already solved by one of the Admins :)
The issue was that the encoding needs to be set to `"multipart"` and that a specific content type needs to be provided which is similar to JSON but needs to be added to the "Accept"-header field.

Here the answer for any future references:

```r
> res <- POST(
    
    url = "https://some/api/endpoint",
    
    body = list(
      file = upload_file("test.csv")
    ),
 
    add_headers(c(
      "Authorization" = token, 
      "Accept" = "specific_format_for_the_application"
   )),

   encode = "multipart",

   verbose()
 )
```